# About the FFT library on Arduino

Tags: signal-processing

From the output results, i see that the arduinoFFT returns only positive frequencies, thus i think it self removes the negative sided values and compensates the lost energy by multiplying by 2. Is this correct?Ar

Comment: What's a "negative" frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by a "negative" frequency.

FFT takes a set of samples and returns a group of "buckets", the number of buckets equal to half the number of samples. These buckets cover frequencies from 0Hz to F/2 where F is the sample frequency.

Each bucket contains the power magnitude of a block of frequencies in both the real and imaginary "axis" (effectively a pair of coordinates depicting a vector).

You compute the absolute power of a bucket through taking the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary components (basically good ol' pythagoras).

This "absolute power" value is the magnitude of a vector. A vector can never have a magnitude < 0. After all, if you have a vector of (1,1) and one of (-1, -1) they are both the same magnitude, just with a different angle (in this example a phase difference of 180 degrees).

Comment: thanks for the answer mister Majenko. Though I just found out  that in the arduinoFFT library, the paramter "FFT_FORWARD" does all the job(returns one sided energy spectrum, and also normalizes the amplitudes).

Comment: I'm not familiar with that specific library or what facilities it provides.

Comment: Last question sir: Would the DC component of the signal affect the amplitudes at other harmonics(components) of the FFT(the FFT is applied to the output signal of an amplified electrt microphone, for some purpose).

Comment: No, the DC component should only affect the DC bucket, if at all

Comment: God bless you. Thanks for the assist ;)

Comment: Please, another question sir: i've tried filtering the sampled data using the Running Mean before running the FFT on it, a way of reducing noise in the output signal of a sensor. However, i'm not sure if it does fit  for an audio signal, as the resulting FFT vector is nothing like the non-filtred one.

Comment: I mean the amplitudes that i get for a certain bin are very different from the ones where no filtering was applied.

Comment: @أيمنالفحصي: that's the whole point of filtering: to alter the amplitude of some frequency components. In the case of a running median, you will be strongly attenuating higher frequencies.

Comment: Actually i'm just interested in the range of 1-8 kHz. Also, the sampling rate that i see the most promising is 20480 Hz,(using the 1.28 factor and the Nyquist theoreme). Also, i'm not filtering the FFT data, but the sampled data(RMS sound pressure versus time). An thoughts on this one please?

Comment: Or maybe  it does have to do with the time that the median calculation takes?? However i can't see why amplitudes of the FFT will change as you mentionned before even runing the FFT.

Comment: You see if we were talking continuous time, things are more easy to get a grasp of. But with the discretized calculations, things aren't that obvious for me   :(